# Computing Marginal Profit Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$C(x)= 0.0004x^3-0.012x^2+100x+10,000$

$R(x)=350x$

I need to find the marginal profit function

So I took

$R'(x)-C'(x)=P'(x)$

$350-.0012x^2-0.024x+100$

I'm confused as how he got the answer on the key which is
$-0.0012x^2+0.024x+250$

Comment: The revenue function is **constant**? That doesn't model reality.

Comment: Sorry I didn't type the X its supposed to be 350x

Comment: Aha, now that you've edited, that looks better.

Comment: I think if you find $R'(x)$, then $C'(x)$, then subtract them, [you'll get the expected answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+350x-(0.0004x%5E3-0.012x%5E2%2B100x%2B10,000)).

Answer (score 1):

### Original Question

$C(x)= 0.0004x^3-0.012x^2+100x+10,000$

$R(x)=350x$

I need to find the marginal profit function

So I took

$R'(x)-C'(x)=P'(x)$

$350-.0012x^2-0.024x+100$

> $C'(x)=3(0.0004)x^2-2(0.012)x+100+0$
>
> $-C'(x)=-.0012x^2+.024x-100$
>
> At this step you forgot to distribute the negative sign completely, it should be $-100$, not positive.
>
> $350-.0012x^2+0.024x-100$
>
> $-.0012x^2+0.024x+250$